# Caffe how to scale and set mean for the same dataset in prototyp

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a `lmdb` which contains values in range [0, 255]. I want to put them in range [-0.5, 0.5]. But I do not know how to do that, since I do not know the order of `scale` and `mean`. Could someone help me out?

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mean_value: 127 ### version 1
    scale: 0.00390625 #### version 1
    mean_value: 0.5 #### version 2
    scale: 0.00390625 #### version 2
  }
  data_param {
    source: "xxx"
    batch_size: 6
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

Which version do I have to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L414-L415) (`TransformationParameter`):

> ```
> // ... Note that the mean subtraction is always carried
> // out before scaling.
> ```

I suppose this answer your question...